# N-Gram Smoothing

Tags: ngrams

I am wondering if there is a good example out there that compares N-Gram with various smoothing techniques.

I found this [notebook](https://github.com/ruthussanketh/natural-language-processing/blob/main/language-models/Language%20Modelling.ipynb) that applies Laplace transform but that is about it. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been many papers on this topic, but you probably should search with the term [language modeling](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=language+model+smoothing) (the name of the main application for smoothing n-grams frequencies).

Apparently there's a [recent paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3130348.3130377), but otherwise you'll most likely find papers from 20 years ago, as this used to be an important question for statistical machine translation (it isn't anymore with neural MT, afaik).